# Unit testing with Angular: how to test changes on parent to child

Tags: angular, unit-testing, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing a component in Angular, using Jasmine.
My test

```js
it('contacts should be passed to child component', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newContact: Contact = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jason Pipemaker'
    };
    const contactsList: Array<Contact> = [newContact];
    contactsComponent.contacts = contactsList;//change on parent component
    tick()
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(childComponents()[0].contacts).toEqual(contactsComponent.contacts);//want to check if changed on child also
    })
}));
```

**I want to test if a change in the parent will reflect on the child**, like happens in a real scenario.

I have tested that the values are equal when everything starts, but I want to test the scenario when one changes the parent value, and that should automatically reflect on the child.

```js
it('contacts should be the same', () => {
   expect(childComponents([0].contacts)
      .toEqual(contactsComponent.contacts);
});
```

Error:

> Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
> Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ id: 1, name: 'Jason Pipemaker' }).

**My interpretation**: it is not waiting for the update to test.

Maybe it is not even a unit test? Since I want to test the binding, maybe it is an integration test.

**Suggestions so far**

*Suggestion 1*: I would try with `contactsComponent.contacts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contactsList))`

comments: Thanks, it does not work. See that I have already tested at the beginning: everything passes. The question would be. Why did it work at the beginning/launching but not after started? I guess this is a problem of somehow making sure everything finishes before testing: an async issue, not JSON.stringify. I have no idea how to make that in code terms! In simple terms: I am changing something on the parent, and want to make sure the child receives the change, like it happens on real scenarios. Thanks for your participation! 
My HTML:

```html
<app-contact-list [contacts]=contacts></app-contact-list>
```

PS. app-contact-list is the child:

```js
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
  .......
  @Input('contacts') contacts: Contact[];//the input for the component
```

*Suggestion 2*: I think you should test the component individually.

Comments:
Regarding mocking the child, I am already mocking using ng-mock

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ContactsComponent, 
         MockComponent(ContactListComponent)],
   }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Drawback: it came to me as private lessons that some organizations do not allow installing those packages, thus, one should mock manually, as suggested.

*Suggestion 3*: You can avoid it by leveraging the async/await syntax.

*Comments*: tried, but did not work, same problem as before. it seems the code is executing before test. I face the same problem with Jest, learnt a trick, that that never happened before. I guess I am missing something like that, something that makes sure the test waits for the final modifications before testing.

**Codes**: some suggested making the codes available.
Here it goes: https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/testing-angular-applications/tree/master/website/src/app/contacts

Maybe someone could make a StackBlitz as suggested!

**Final solution**

In order to close this issue, I have decided to test in a simple case, as so the core idea under test would be the only concern. See the full simple application [here](https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/angulartypescript/tree/master/code-samples/Angular9/chapter8/inter-component/src/app/input) before testing. And see the final testing file [here](https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/angular-unit-testing/blob/main/order.componenent.spec.ts).

I draw insights from both answers, and accepted the one that helped me the most, even the comments helped.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I would try with `contactsComponent.contacts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contactsList))`

Comment: Thanks, it does not work. See that I have already tested at the beginning: everything passes. The question would be. Why did it work at the beginning/launching but not after started? I guess this is a problem of somehow making sure everything finishes before testing: an async issue, not JSON.stringify. I have no idea how to make that in code terms! Thanks for your participation! 

Comment: If you could make a simple `Stackblitz` would be perfect to analyze!

Comment: I don't have time for a detailed answer, but you can use `fixture.detectChanges()` to force a render within the TestBed.  Depending on your specifics your may need to combine that with a `fakeAsync` block and `tick()` or `async` and `whenStable()`.  That said, my preference for unit testing is to mock dependencies as best I can. The child should be testable independently of the parent and vice versa. For testing full screens--not components--I prefer E2E testing.

Comment: I thought about a Stackblitz, I will consider that.

Comment: For such tests angular has https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host technique. And why do you need tick and fakeAsync there?

Comment: I tried without it, and it did not work. So I tried this way. There is no need, I prefer simplicity, when possible.

Comment: I am reading a full book about unit testing, and it seems it is an integration according to the London School, but can be unit testing according to the classical school.

Comment: `maybe it is an integration test` - yes, it is. And I find them very useful. If you want to treat the fact of all test passing as a sign that the app really works as expected, integration tests would be very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should test the component individually. In your `ContactListComponent`, test if it contains the right contacts. Something like the simple test below. Testing the child is a completly other test so mock the child component.

```
  it('have the correct contacts', () => {
    expect(component.contacts[0].id).toBe(1);
    expect(component.contacts[0].name).toBe('value');
  });
```

Simple mock example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component'
  template: ''
})
class TestChildComponent {
  @Input() contact;
}
```

Now, you want to test your `ChildComponent`. This can be done by stubbing a parent and test if the child reflects the correct data.

Example:

```
@Component({
  template: '<child-component [contact]="contact"></child-component>'
})
class TestHostComponent {
  contact = new Contact();
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) component: ChildComponent;
}

describe('ChildComponent', () => {
  let component: ChildComponent;
  let host: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ChildComponent, TestHostComponent],
      ...
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    host = fixture.componentInstance;
    component = host.component;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be able to present a contact', () => {
    host.contact = new Contact('otherValue');
    expect(SomeQuery.value).toBe('otherValue')
  }); 

});
```

EDIT:

Instead of mocking the child component, you could instead add the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  ...
});
```

This will prevent angular from raising errors when components could not be found. Use with caution because this could give the false impression everything is fine.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look and come back to you soon! 

Comment: it seems you created the mock manually. What about this library: https://www.google.com/search?client=avast-a-1&q=ng+mock&oq=ng+mock&aqs=avast..69i57j0l4j69i60l3.3215j0j7&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I used it, and liked it. The only drawback is that some companies have policies against installing those packages.

Comment: Facing problems here ``` import { TestbedHarnessEnvironment } from "@angular/cdk/testing"
``` did some research, found no solution. This called my attention: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5803

Comment: it seems this library is not public.

Comment: I don't think it is relevant how to do the mocking. Whatever you are comfortable with and works of course. Also, see my edit as an alternative to mocking the child.

Comment: Trying to implement this solution on a simpler problem. What is ```SomeQuery```?

Comment: The solution did not solve the poblem, but I liked the idea of host,, tested and worked. it seems it is on the documentation. thanks

Comment: SomeQuery could be any query to get the value from the screen. Some example: `const title = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement;`

Comment: Tried getting the actual child, did not work. ```    function childComponents(): ContactListComponent[] {
        return fixture.debugElement
            .queryAll(By.directive(ContactListComponent))
            .map(el => el.componentInstance);
    }
```

Comment: Tested if the child was taken, and it was

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach of testing bindings and do the same in my code as well. The provided test is almost right. Just a small issue with asynchronicity. The code inside `fixture.whenStable().then(` would be executed after the test would be considered by karma as finished. You can avoid it by leveraging the `async`/`await` syntax.

```js
it('contacts should be passed to child component', aynsc () => {
    const newContact: Contact = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jason Pipemaker'
    };
    const contactsList: Array<Contact> = [newContact];
    contactsComponent.contacts = contactsList;//set on parent component

    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(childComponents()[0].contacts)
       .toEqual(contactsComponent.contacts);//want to check if changed on child also
}));

it('child component should receive data when data in parent is changed', aynsc () => {
    const firstContact: Contact = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jason Pipemaker'
    };
    const contactsList: Array<Contact> = [firstContact];
    contactsComponent.contacts = contactsList;//set on parent component
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    const secondContact: Contact = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jason Pipemaker'
    };

    const contactsList2: Array<Contact> = [firstContact, secondContact];
    contactsComponent.contacts = contactsList2;//change on parent component
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(childComponents()[0].contacts)
       .toEqual(contactsComponent.contacts);//want to check if changed on child also
}));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, tested it, same problem. The test is not waiting for being tested. Thanks!  What you said makes sense, that is what I think as well. I faced this problem with Jest, until I have learnt two tricks on Jest, it never happened again. I am missing something. I will try to test your technique on a simpler problem, maybe the problem is my code. I will let you know.

Comment: Can you prepare a simple example? It does not seem to be difficult? I will try as well!

Comment: sorry, I didn't find time to prepare an example. happy to know you solved it